# It's no longer possible to map data types to function arguments in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have this code in [a project of mine](https://github.com/blixt/asteroids) but I can no longer find a way to do this conversion in TypeScript, every attempt seems to fail:

```js
// Define data containers with a factory function.
// Create a type with argument/return types, e.g.:
// ComponentId<[number], {amount: number}>

const friction = world.addComponent('friction', (amount: number) => ({amount}));
const velocity = world.addComponent('velocity', (vx: number, vy: number) => ({vx, vy}));

// Add a function that will run over the specified components. The storages
// for the components provided will be added as arguments to the function.
// Basically, turn a ComponentId list into a function signature:
// (world, entities, frictions: {get(…): {amount: number}}, …)

world.addSystem(
  'friction',
  [friction, velocity],
  (world, entities, frictions, velocities) => {
    const dt = world.globals.deltaTime;
    for (const {id} of entities) {
      const {amount} = frictions.get(id);
      const velocity = velocities.get(id);
      velocity.vx *= 1 - amount * dt;
      velocity.vy *= 1 - amount * dt;
    }
  },
);
```

Basically in older versions of TypeScript (~3.1 or so) this was doable (see the [GitHub source code for how](https://github.com/blixt/asteroids)) but now I don't see how to map the input array `[friction, velocity]` into correctly typed arguments into the function argument in `addSystem`...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: Here's a simplified example of the types:

```js
interface ComponentId<I, O> {}

function createComponent<I extends any[], O>(
    factory: (...input: I) => O
): ComponentId<I, O> {
    return "normally this would be an identifier for the component"
}

// Create a component, which now has underlying type:
// ComponentId<[number, number], {x: number, y: number}>
const positionComponent = createComponent((x: number, y: number) => ({x, y}))
// And another...
const velocityComponent = createComponent((vx: number, vy: number) => ({vx, vy}))

// This is where the magic should happen...
type TurnComponentIdListIntoArguments<???> = ???

// step(...) should be a function that receives the
// "O" type of every ComponentId as an argument.
function createSystem<C extends ???>(
    components: C,
    step: (...values: TurnComponentIdListIntoArguments<C>) => void
): void {
    // This part doesn't matter...
}

const moveSystem = createSystem(
    [positionComponent, velocityComponent],
    (position, velocity) => {
        // For simplicity's sake, let's say we'd expect position and velocity to be:
        // {x: number, y: number} and {vx: number, vy: number}
    })
```

Comment: Opened the repo in VS-Code, TS 3.5.2, I see`frictions: ReadonlyStorage<{
    amount: number;
}>` and `velocities: ReadonlyStorage<{
    vx: number;
    vy: number;
}>` which seem right .. what is not working and are you sure you are using the right TS version ?

Comment: Also don't  use recursive conditional types, there are no guarantees about if and how the will work in the future:https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-513187373

Comment: Could you share some of the underlying types here?  What's your current type for that function?  Types for `addSystem` and `addComponent` would also be useful.  Without that info, my first thought would be leveraging generics and the spread operator.  If you always know that the function will take `inputArray.length + 2` inputs, then you may be able to declare each slot as a generic and pass it through.  One big issue, though, is that you can't do an arbitrary number of generics -- there's no way to say, "Some number of args which may all have different types", only "n args w/ different types"

Comment: @ohsully actually that is possible using tuples in rest parameters. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir The more you know!  That `tuple` function is clever, addresses a problem I ran into recently.  I imagine that the typing would pass through just fine with `const [myStr, myNum] = tuple('foo', 2)`?

Comment: @ohsully I tried to simplify the problem in the second code snippet that I added to my question now.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Yeah I've seen that warning about recursiveness before. Anyway, the types get all wonky in TypeScript 3.5. It might be my recursive mapping... I'm thinking overloading up to 4 components is okay too

Comment: @Blixt I am not sure why you are using the recursive version, the only thing in there is the `void` special case filtering, which I don't think you can solve well with overloads anyway. If you drop the `void` special case, you can use a mapped type to map the tuple (supported, since 3.1 I believe)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I'm trying but I can't find any way to make the output tuple smaller than the input (even if using `never`) so the only way to skip the `void` types in the storage list is to use a recursive type...

Comment: @Blixt Thanks for adding those types -- I gave it some more thought, but I also can't figure out a way around the -arity issues.  Maybe you can get a similar development experience with a different pattern, like having the `step` function take an object of named values.  The interface could say they're optional, then you just cast them as existing at the top of the function:

`interface StepData { positionComponent?: Position, velocityComponent?: Velocity }`

`({ positionComponent, velocityComponent }) => { const position = positionComponent as Position; }`